# Why does runtime.Caller(0) return the path in which the binary was built?

Tags: go

As question title tells, the `runtime.Caller(0)` returns a path which is actually where the binary was built (a path in my build env), not the path where the current binary is located.

This is a bit hard to understand for me, how the build-time info was injected and brought into the runtime?

I have some code like this:

```
_, f, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
cfg.ProjRootPath = filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(f), "../..")
```

Then my pipeline (build env) builds the binary, then I take the binary to some other testing environment, and the `cfg.ProjRootPath` gives me some path which only exists in my build env, something like: `/j/prod-build7899/src/....`, that is exactly where the project source code is located on the build pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

`runtime.Caller(0)` returns information about the *call stack*, not the working directory. The file name and line number of course refer to the source code used to compile the executable.

Also, the underlying implementation is platform specific.

If you want the working directory (absolute path), use `os.Executable`:

> Executable returns the path name for the executable that started the current process.

^ from the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable

Comment: Important to note here is that the "working directory" is not the project source WD but the path of your binary. In my case, I needed to make reference to a `.env` file but when I use `go run ./src/main.go`, using `os.Executable` returns `/private/var/folder/1g....` and it doesn't find my `./.env` whereas it finds it when I run my containerized app (from a scratch dockerfile). The solution for me was to use `curDir, err := os.Getwd()` then `loadErr := godotenv.Load(curDir + "/.env")`

Answer (score 3):

> This is a bit hard to understand for me, how the build-time info was injected and bring into the runtime?

The compiler placed that info into the executable while creating the executable from source code. This information is available at runtime because it is contained (as metadata) in the executable binary.